# Managing Images and media files in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've used `bundling` in MVC4 for managing `css` and `js` files but I didn't find a good solution for managing/caching images and media files in MVC4.

Should I run another static file server for that?

Comment: You can set caching in IIS, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to configure caching in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo Thanks for reply but I think I should find some better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure IIS cache headers for the static content via web.config and the [`staticContent/clientCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689443.aspx) element.

Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="01:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For a one hour cache policy.